# Stop VS Code side bar from collapsing folders when i click anywhere on the sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I keep the side bar from collapsing all my folders when i click anywhere on the file structure?

So clicking any where on the side bar brings the whole thing from:

```
folder1
-file1
folder2
-file2
-folder3
--file3
```

to:

```
folder1
folder2
```

everytime and it's honestly super annoying. I can't find anything that seems right in the settings menu under the name explorer or side bar so if someone has a specific setting to search that would be super helpful.

Comment: Is this reproducible on a fresh VS code installation?

Comment: @carlfriedrich I doubt it. This only started a week or two ago and i've been using it on this pc for 2.5 months now.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the contents of your `settings.json` then?